# get() returned more than one Modules -- it returned 2! (REST API - Django)

Tags: python, django, api, rest

Here are my models:

```py
class Modules(models.Model):
    module_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    module_duration = models.IntegerField()
    class_room = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.module_name
class Students(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    grade = models.IntegerField()
    modules = models.ManyToManyField(Modules)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here are my views:

````py
class StudentsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = StudentsSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        student = Students.objects.all()
        return student
    def create(self,request,*args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        new_student = Students.objects.create(name=data["name"], age=data['age'], grade=data["grade"])
        new_student.save()
        for module in data["modules"]:
            module_obj = Modules.objects.get(module_name=module["module_name"])
            new_student.modules.add(module_obj)
        serializer = StudentsSerializer(new_student)
        return Response(serializer.data)
class ModulesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ModudesSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        module = Modules.objects.all()
        return module    ```
````

When I post this:

```
*{
    "name": "steve",
    "age": 16,
    "grade": 10,
    "modules": [
        {
            "module_name": "math"
        },
        {
            "module_name": "physics"
        }
    ]
}*
```

It says:

```
MultipleObjectsReturned at /app_Five/student/
get() returned more than one Modules -- it returned 2!
```

I understand that `get()` only gets one element. But I think in the`for` loop above, only one `module_name` exists for each loop. So each time the `get()` executes, there's only one result for it to get. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong there?

Comment: To check the problem, you could replace the line with ` Modules.objects.filter(module_name=module["module_name"])` and then log/print the found modules. Maybe in your database exist more than one instance with a given name.

Comment: It means your database contains multiple `Module` objects with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you expect the module name to be unique. You probably have multiple `Modules` entries in the database with the same `module_name`.

To ensure unique names when creating Module entries you could change the Modules model to enforce this:

```
class Modules(models.Model):
    module_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)
    module_duration = models.IntegerField()
...
```